# Edit invalid password rules and error message

Tags: dotnetnuke

When registering as a new user on our custom DotNetNuke website, if we enter a password that is incorrect an error message displays stating "The password specified is invalid. Please specify a valid password. Passwords must be at least 7 characters in length and contain at least 0 non-alphanumeric characters.".

Is there any way that this error message can be edited, as well as the rules? So for instance we want there to be at least one number in the password and for it to be between 8 and 10 characters. Can this be done? And where could I do it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've just found out how to do it from this post: http://www.dotnetnuke.com/Resources/Forums/forumid/89/postid/218801/scope/posts.aspx

Looks like its all editable from the web.config file